# How to query the shadowDOM in an Angular component test

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have this unit-test setup and want to examine the `shadowDOM` of the `<rating>` element.
But the `shadowDOM` has no childNodes.

In the code below I try to examine the elements shadowDOM in the `getStars()` method.

Is there a flaw in my approach?
Should this work?

```dart
library bootstrap_angular.test.elements.rating;

import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:unittest/html_enhanced_config.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart' as ng;
import 'package:angular/mock/module.dart' as ngMock;

import 'package:bootstrap_angular/rating/rating.dart';

void main() {
  useHtmlEnhancedConfiguration();

  ng.Scope _rootScope;
  dom.Element _element;
  ngMock.TestBed _tb;
  ngMock.MockHttpBackend _backend;

  setUp(() {
    Future f;
    try {
    ngMock.setUpInjector();

      ngMock.module((ng.Module module) {
        module.install(new RatingModule());
      });

      ngMock.inject((ng.Scope scope, ngMock.TestBed testBed) {
        _rootScope = scope;
        _rootScope['rate'] = 3;
        _tb = testBed;

        f = dom.HttpRequest.getString('/bootstrap_angular/packages/bootstrap_angular/rating/rating.html')
        .then((ratingTemplate) {
          _backend = new ngMock.MockHttpBackend();

          assert(ratingTemplate.contains('<i '));
          _backend.expect('GET').respond(ratingTemplate);

          _element = _tb.compile('<rating value="rate"></rating>', scope: _rootScope);
          var element =_element.shadowRoot.querySelector('i');
          _rootScope.$digest();
        }).catchError((e) => print(e));
      });
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return f;
  });

  List<dom.Element> getStars() {
    print(_element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('i'));
    return _element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('i');
  }

  test("rating component", ( ) {
    expect(getStars().length, equals(3));
  });
}
```

**The elements template HTML returned from the HTTP request**

```html
    <span ng-mouseleave="ctrl.reset()">
      <i ng-repeat="r in ctrl.range" ng-mouseenter="ctrl.enter($index + 1)" ng-click="ctrl.rate($index + 1)" class="glyphicon" ng-class="ctrl.stateClass($index, r)"></i>
    </span>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: The element's shadowDOM has content when inserted into a demo page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic approach should work.

For the AngularDart tests, we have a `JQuery` class in [test/_specs.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/test/_specs.dart#L223) which handles peeking into the shadow DOM.  For example see the `JQuery.textWithShadow()` method.

Looking at the code you posted, I suspect you have a race condition in that you aren't waiting for the compile to complete.  Depending on the rating component, the compile may be asynchronous: possibly you need to flush the MockHttpBackend.

In the AngularDart tests, we deal with this using the `async()` concept, which will fail your test if you leave Futures hanging.  See [lib/mock/zone](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/mock/zone.dart#L141) in the AngularDart Github repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I had to run `compile` inside `zone.run(() {compile(element, directives)(injector, view)});`