# How can an Angular component query its own shadow DOM?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

[The following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061629/how-to-query-the-shadowdom-in-an-angular-component-test) asks "How to query the shadowDOM in an Angular component **test**", but I don't want to achieve this in a unit testing context, but the actual component.

Specifically, I have a component whose **template** contains a canvas that I would like a reference to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `ShadowRootAware` and override `onShadowRoot()` to obtain a reference to `ShadowRoot`, which in turn can be used for querying. (using `.querySelector`)